# Java's PushbackReader and EOF

Tags: java, parsing, eof

I am writing a parser in Java and trying to leverage Java's PushbackReader. My parser may need to backtrack if it guessed incorrectly - but once the reader reaches EOF, that fails.

Let's say I am parsing a quoted String and I'm looking for the closing quotes. If any of my parser plugins can't completely finish, they try to leave the reader in the original state and pass it to the next plugin. IE: I generally push chars back onto the buffer and let the next element try to parse the buffer.

Unfortunately, if I 'read' all the way to the last character ... and then read the EOF, the PushbackReader will not allow me to push anything back onto it. Consequently, my parsing can't complete since those chars are lost!

Do I need to write my own reader for this type of string processing?

EDIT: furthermore, when I read the last character (the one just before EOF), I can't "unread" that char either. Is there a standard workaround for this - short of creating my own stack or buffer implementation?

Comment: seems unlikely. your code may have problems.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful to never unread the EOF marker, the buffer inside PushbackReader is of type char[], so the integer -1 will get converted to char 0xFFFF, which will then be the next character returned from the read method. For example when parsing a quoted String always include a check for -1 in addition to the ending quote character and handle this as a failure case, for example by throwing an IOException.

Comment: That's a great point. Thanks. I guess PushbackReader just isn't suited to this parsing task.

Comment: @Luther Baker, I have used PushbackReader for parsing before, but only in cases where I only needed up to 3 characters of lookahead, and it worked fine. Can you include some more information on the grammar you are parsing? If you need to backtrack to the beginning of a String you might also look at the `mark` and `reset` methods of BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciated this question and answer because it saved me time looking into a solution that wasn't suited for what I needed which was a PushbackLineReader.

I was parsing a log file and needed a block of data with `pattern one` and `pattern two` in it as shown.

```
TIMESTAMP pattern one
several lines with pattern two
next line <<< I need to read this line to know I'm at the end of pattern two
TIMESTAMP pattern one
several lines with pattern two
TIMESTAMP pattern one <<< I need to read this but also push it back
several lines with pattern two
```

So I needed to read an entire line and then when I read one line past the line that had `pattern two`, I need to push back the line just read.

I decided writing my own class to do that.  Which given I only had one line to push back was simple enough

```
class MyPushbackLineReader {
    private String pushedBackLine;

    String readLine() {
        String rtn = pushedBackLine
        if (pushedBackLine == null){
            rtn = reader.readLine();
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```